# set geolocation in data object after mounted vuejs

Tags: javascript, geolocation, vue.js

I'm relatively new to VueJS scene. Recently I'm trying to work on my side project which requires to get User's Geolocation Data as soon as the main component had mounted.

My code is here,

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: {
    position: null
  },
  mounted: function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        this.position = position.coords;
      })
    }

  }
});
```

I wanted to set `position` in data object to current geolocation after mounted but unfortunately it isn't working. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Could you log error callback inside the getCurrentPosition ? Basically it would work only on secure origin - if you are working on localhost It should work, but if you are ony site that doesn't use https it would throw error that could be catched with error callback,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's context issue, this inside navigator is bounded to wrong context, so when you write `this.position`, `this` is not set to Vue object.

To prevent that you can use arrow functions:

```
  mounted: function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.position = position.coords;
      })
    }
  }
```

or declate the variable before navigator object that would hold correct context

```
  mounted: function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
       var self = this;
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        self.position = position.coords;
      })
    }
  }
```

BTW just let you know - the `position.coords` would return Object that holds properties such as `latitude`, `longitude` etc, so If you want one of them you will need point that:

```
self.position = position.coords.latitude;
```